# Build failure - No instances of com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.SerializedString are allowed in the image heap

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

I am working on switching a module inside an existing spring-boot project to use spring native. My nativeBuild is failing with the error below.

> Fatal error:com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError$ParsingError:
> Error encountered while parsing
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory._createGenerator(java.io.Writer,
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.IOContext) Parsing context: parsing
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createGenerator(JsonFactory.java:1318)
> parsing
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.createGenerator(ObjectMapper.java:1164)
> parsing
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:3725)
> parsing a.b.c.Util.writeManifest(Util.java:61)
>
> Caused by:
> org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError:
> com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: No
> instances of com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.SerializedString are
> allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image
> runtime. To see how this object got instantiated use
> --trace-object-instantiation=com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.SerializedString.
> at parsing
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.(JsonFactory.java:186) at
> jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.throwParserError(BytecodeParser.java:2601)

This is triggered at this piece of code:

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  mapper.writeValue(writer, convertedResults);
```

I am using:

> id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.2'   id
> 'org.springframework.experimental.aot' version '0.10.1'   id
> 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.9.0' nativeBuild {
> buildArgs("--trace-object-instantiation=com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.SerializedString
> --verbose -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces") }
>
> openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 OpenJDK Runtime Environment
> GraalVM CE 21.1.0 (build 11.0.11+8-jvmci-21.1-b05) OpenJDK 64-Bit
> Server VM GraalVM CE 21.1.0 (build 11.0.11+8-jvmci-21.1-b05, mixed
> mode, sharing)

I tried reproducing this issue in a standalone spring native project, however, did not run into the same problem.
Would you have any pointers on how I can go about investigating this further?

Thanks!

Comment: try --rerun-class-initialization-at-runtime=com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.SerializedString

Comment: Thanks @MunishChouhan, unfortunately the error did not go away with this too.

Comment: you can post your error with reproducer here https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues